# Codingbat countYZ

Tags: java, regex

Task from [Codingbat](https://codingbat.com/prob/p199171%5D) :

Given a string, count the number of words ending in 'y' or 'z' -- so the 'y' in "heavy" and the 'z' in "fez" count, but not the 'y' in "yellow" (not case sensitive). We'll say that a y or z is at the end of a word if there is not an alphabetic letter immediately following it. (Note: `Character.isLetter(char)` tests if a char is an alphabetic letter.)

```
countYZ("fez day") → 2
countYZ("day fez") → 2
countYZ("day fyyyz") → 2
```

I'm trying to solve this task like this:

```
public int countYZ(String str) {
      String regex = "(.[.^y^z]\\b)";
      return str.toLowerCase().replaceAll(regex, "").length();
    }
```

But not all the tests were passed. How can I fix regex = "(.[.^y^z]\b)" in order to pass all the tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could capture either y or z in a capture group not followed by a char a-z, and match any other char.

In the replacement use capture group 1.

```
([yYzZ](?![A-Za-z]))|.
```

**Explanation**

- `(` Capture group 1

  - `[yYzZ]` Match y or z in lower or uppercase
  - `(?![A-Za-z])` Negative lookahead, assert not a char A-Za-z directly to the right
- `)` Close group 1
- `|` Or
- `.` Match any other character

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MqsfoF/1) and a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/GeKHOd).

Example

```
public int countYZ(String str) {
  String regex = "([yYzZ](?![A-Za-z]))|.";
    return str.toLowerCase().replaceAll(regex, "$1").length();
}
```

Or the unicode variant for a broader match:

```
public int countYZ(String str) {
  String regex = "([YyZz])(?!\\p{IsAlphabetic})|.";
    return str.toLowerCase().replaceAll(regex, "$1").length();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this code does not pass all the tests on Codingbat.

Comment: @EugeneKhlebnikov Now the code does pass all tests.

Answer (score -1):

Better to restrict using regex where you can do so.
You can make the solution like this:

```
public static int countYZ(String str) {
    String[] strings = str.toLowerCase().split("\\s");
    int n = 0;
    for (String s : strings) {
        if (s.endsWith("y") || s.endsWith("z")) {
            n++;
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Your code does not work, for example, in this case: countYZ("!!day--yaz!!")

Comment: Sure, as I understand from comments, words should be separated with spaces. In the point of any symbols we should use regex. Replace first line of written method with this one:
`String[] strings = str.toLowerCase().split("\\W");`.